# Does allowing SSLv3 or TLSv1.0 weaken other protocols? (TLSv1.2+)

Tags: tls

I know that SSL and TLS below v1.2 are insecure and should not be used.

By allowing the use of those insecure protocols, can that expose connections using the stronger TLSv1.2+ protocols to any vulnerabilities?

If I have some users who refuse to move off TLSv1.0, can I leave that protocol enabled on an 'at your own risk' basis without compromising the more sane users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no currently known attacks like that. If your server does [SCSV](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7507) then modern TLS 1.2 or TLS 1.3 clients should be safe. But a future attack might be discovered that uses old protocols to attack connections using new protocol. A famous example is [DROWN](https://drownattack.com/), in which if your server also supports SSLv2 or the private key for your certificate was used in a certificate that is used by an SSLv2 server (possibly different certificate, possibly different server), your TLS connections are vulnerable.

Note that some regulatory bodies prohibit leaving TLS 1.0 enabled.

Ask your users when they plan to upgrade from TLS 1.0. Their TLS 1.0-only client will become not very useful very fast. It is already not able to use credit card payments.

Set a deadline for your own support of TLS 1.0. A reasonable deadline is [June 2018](https://blog.pcisecuritystandards.org/are-you-ready-for-30-june-2018-sayin-goodbye-to-ssl-early-tls). We're a bit past that, so don't set your own deadline too far in the future.

Remind them that [TLS 1.2 was released in 2008](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246). [Chrome has supported TLS 1.2 since version 29 in 2013](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome_version_history).

I should add that there is a subtlety that is not apparent from just looking at the version number. The protocol TLS 1.0 is not completely busted, if it is implemented and configured correctly. I think a modern openssl 1.1.1 based server would be fine, communicating to a modern openssl 1.1.1 client (like a recentish version of python/ruby/php), even when limited to TLS 1.0. The problem is that a modern TLS client would support TLS 1.2 and AEAD cipher suites, and there is no reason to limit it to TLS 1.0. A TLS client that was implemented before TLS 1.2 was specified and has not been updated since is highly likely to be insecure. I would bet money on it being insecure. It is possible that the client has been patched since then and is secure, but if it could be patched, why couldn't it be updated to a version that supports TLS 1.2?

It turned out that implementing the TLS CBC cipher suites securely is too damn hard. All the major players had vulnerabilities, some of them needed multiple attempts to fix it (e.g. s2n), some made worse vulnerabilities while trying to fix it (e.g. openssl), some just gave up and recommended a switch to AEAD only configuration for those who are worried (e.g. golang). Some are still not fixed. An internet wide scan showed that vulnerable servers are still deployed, so a client connecting to a random internet site that supports only TLS CBC cipher suites is not guaranteed that the connection is secure. The browser vendors are going to ratchet the whole ecosystem, kicking and screaming, into PFS+AEAD. But it will take years, because some people expect to use a Red Hat server for a decade without upgrading. Note that [HTTP2 standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540) has already said that only PFS+AEAD is secure, and lower security cipher suites are not allowed for HTTP2. In 2015. [TLS 1.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446) only supports PFS+AEAD. That was out in 2018.

Comment: I wonder who these TLS 1.0-only people are. Where did they come from? And why are they 20 years behind us?

Answer (score 1):

No, allowing TLS1.0 connections wont affect users who are connected with TLS1.2 or higher. There's no cross communication between TLS sessions set up between your server and the clients.

When your server tries to establish a TLS handshake with the client, they will share their lists of enabled protocols and cipher suites to find a mutually shared option. Once a protocol and cipher suite are agreed on, they move to complete the rest of the handshake to open the encrypted tunnel. You can read a more detailed overview of the TLS handshake in [this cloudflare article.](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/ssl/what-happens-in-a-tls-handshake/)

You could configure your server to allow TLS1.0, or TLS1.1 but only if TLS1.2 is unavailable. The problem with this approach is that it's relatively easy for an attacker to disable TLS1.2 or TLS1.1 on his machine and force downgrade the TLS protocol to make it easier to attack. I cant recommend leaving TLS1 enabled, I would also be wary of TLS1.1. Ideally, you want only TLS1.2 or higher. You could allow users to connect with TLS1, but thats opening up those users to a lot of attack vectors.

While the users using TLS1 dont pose a direct risk to others using TLS1.2, it can pose an indirect threat. Its possible an attacker could somehow exploit the TLS1 connection to get access to your server, potentially exposing the other users who were only on TLS1.2.